# How to compare Microsoft.Exchange.Common.ScheduleInterval with a datetime object?

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I want find out if there is any Exchange database schedule running, or will run in the next few hours.  However, I couldn't figure out how to compare the scheduleinterval object with a variable I created with get-date or (get-date).addhours(20)

The scheduleInterval I am looking at is

```
C:\>(get-mailboxdatabase | where {$_.name -like 'database'}).maintenanceschedule  | Get-Member

   TypeName: Microsoft.Exchange.Common.ScheduleInterval

Name         MemberType Definition
----         ---------- ----------
CompareTo    Method     int CompareTo(System.Object value), int CompareTo(Microsoft.Exchange.Common.ScheduleInterval...
ConjointWith Method     bool ConjointWith(Microsoft.Exchange.Common.ScheduleInterval other)
Contains     Method     bool Contains(Microsoft.Exchange.Common.WeekDayAndTime dt), bool Contains(System.DateTime dt...
Equals       Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode  Method     int GetHashCode()
GetType      Method     type GetType()
Overlaps     Method     bool Overlaps(Microsoft.Exchange.Common.ScheduleInterval other)
ToString     Method     string ToString()
EndDay       Property   System.DayOfWeek EndDay {get;}
EndHour      Property   System.Int32 EndHour {get;}
EndMinute    Property   System.Int32 EndMinute {get;}
EndTime      Property   Microsoft.Exchange.Common.WeekDayAndTime EndTime {get;}
Length       Property   System.TimeSpan Length {get;}
StartDay     Property   System.DayOfWeek StartDay {get;}
StartHour    Property   System.Int32 StartHour {get;}
StartMinute  Property   System.Int32 StartMinute {get;}
StartTime    Property   Microsoft.Exchange.Common.WeekDayAndTime StartTime {get;}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a way to test if a job is running at the `Get-Date` value.
Maybe the comparison can be done casting `starttime/endtime properties` to `[datetime]` but I can't test, I'm just supposing..

```
$a = (get-mailboxdatabase | where {$_.name -like 'database'}).maintenanceschedule
$b = Get-date # you can add days to check events in the future
if ( $a.startday, $a.endday -contains $b.dayofweek)
{
  if ( $a.starthour -le $b.hour -and $a.endhour -ge $b.hour)
  {
    if (  $a.startminute -le $b.minute -and $a.endminute -ge $b.minute)
    {
       Write-Host "Jod scheduled is running at this time!"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It took me quite a while to understand the logic of your code.  Thanks again.

Comment: BTW, is there an easy way to find the next coming schedule?

Comment: @BarryChum I can't test because I don't have a exchange 2007/2010 to working on, but you need to work on the output of maintenanceschedule properties (maybe is an array???) and doing some date/time parsing to seek next coming scheduled job.

Comment: @BarryChum The code im my answer can have best performance if you test first minutes then hours and then days... but I'm talking about milliseconds ;)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the following codes to convert the Microsoft.Exchange.Common.ScheduleInterval into an array of datetime objects.  Hope someone can improve my codes...

```
$schedules=(get-mailboxdatabase|where {$_.name -like "dbname"}).maintenanceschedule 

$curdatetime = get-date
$dowhash = @{"Monday"=1;"Tuesday"=2;"Wednesday"=3;"Thursday"=4; `
             "Friday"=5;"Saturday"=6;"Sunday"=7}
$todaydow = $dowhash.get_item([string]$curdatetime.dayofweek)
$coming = @()

foreach ($schedule in $schedules) {
  $dow = $dowhash.get_item([string]$schedule.startday)
  $start = $curdatetime.adddays((($dow+7-$todaydow) % 7))
  $startstr = "{0:yyyyMMdd}{1:00}{2:00}" `
              -f $start,$schedule.starthour,$schedule.startminute

  $dow = $dowhash.get_item([string]$schedule.endday)
  $end = $curdatetime.adddays((($dow+7-$todaydow) % 7))
  $endstr   = "{0:yyyyMMdd}{1:00}{2:00}" `
              -f $end,$schedule.endhour,$schedule.endminute

  $coming+=,([datetime]::ParseExact($startstr,"yyyyMMddHHmm",$null), `
             [datetime]::ParseExact($endstr,"yyyyMMddHHmm",$null) )
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What is `$weekschedule` ? I can't see where you define it in your sample code.

Comment: I missed them when I copied and pasted.  I've update my codes. cheers,